# How to make a UserControl object behave as a Design-Time control container in "ASP.NET"

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

How to make a UserControl object behave as a Design-Time control container in "ASP.NET". I want to be able drag any controls inside UserControl in design time. I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322222) but it is for Windows Forms and not for ASP.net WebFoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't drag controls into the user control from the designer-view of the page, but you should be able to drag controls from the designer-view of the user control.

If you're looking for something more than that, you'll need to develop a custom server control that inherits from `TemplateControl`, and you'll need to specify the correct attributes so that it's usable in the design-view.

Comment: It's the thought that counts ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer james. but can you describe more about develop a custom server control that inherits from TemplateControl? I have a tabcontrol that I want to use it in all of my asp.net web application content pages without recreating it in every page. so I think best way is to use a usercontrol but now it's not possible to drag any control inside it in content page. kind regards